# Generating header file with JNI using 'javah'

Tags: java, android, opencv, java-native-interface, javah

I'm trying to use JNI for an Android application using the OpenCV4Android library. I can generate a header file without using the opencv library, but I get an error whenever the class imports anything. I assume it needs to link to the library, but I'm not sure how to do that? I'm using cygwin on a Windows 8.1 64 bit machine.

original output:

```
$ javah -jni -classpath ./bin/classes -d jni/ com.example.icam.nativeRDE  
Error: Class org.opencv.core.Mat could not be found.
```

After following advice from: [Android, generate jni Header Files with javah , show error that can't find org.opencv.core.Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438368/android-generate-jni-header-files-with-javah-show-error-that-cant-find-org-o), I get the following output:

```
$ javah -classpath /cygdrive/c/Users/Majid/Documents/OpenCV4Android/OpenCVLib2.4.8/bin/classes/org/opencv/;/cygdrive/c/Users/Majid/Documents/OpenCV4Android/iCam/bin/classes/com/example/icam/ -jni -d jni/ com.example.icam.nativeRDE
Error: no classes specified
-bash: /cygdrive/c/Users/Majid/Documents/OpenCV4Android/iCam/bin/classes/com/example/icam/: is a directory
```

I've tried:

- removing '/' after icam
- adding nativeRDE after 'icam/'
- adding nativeRDE.class after 'icam/'

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android, generate jni Header Files with javah , show error that can't find org.opencv.core.Mat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438368/android-generate-jni-header-files-with-javah-show-error-that-cant-find-org-o)

Comment: I tried following the advice from that thread, but got errors. I should've mentioned it my original post, but I've now edited it.

Comment: have you tried `javah -classpath c:\Users\Majid\Documents\OpenCV4Android\OpenCVLib2.4.8\bin\classes\org\opencv;c:\Users\Majid\Documents\OpenCV4Android\iCam\bin\classes\com\example\icam -jni -d jni/ com.example.icam.nativeRDE`? Or maybe (I don't have the environment ready to verify), you can use forward (Unix-style) slash **/**. The reason is that **javah** is not a **cygwin** executable, therefore it does not understand `/cygdrive`. You already noticed that you need **";"** separator in Windows, not **":"** as in the [referenced topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438368)

Comment: Yes, but it still was not working. I think I have a workaround, so hopefully should be fine.

Comment: generally speaking, you don't need `javah` to build and run your JNI code on Android.

Comment: On the 2nd use of javah, I would expect cygwin to parse the line as two commands, separated by that semicolon.  That would explain why bash complained about finding a directory -- it wanted an executable after the semicolon.

Answer (score 5):

Javah takes a fully qualified class name, and classpath.
Class name must be with full package name.
Ex:`fullPackageName.className`

Class path is your src folder not bin folder
Your classpath must be `c\Users\Majid\Documents\OpenCV4Android\iCam\src`

`Javah -jni -classpath` `C:\ProjectName\src` `com.abc.YourClassName`

Answer (score 5):

## **Solution: Generating header file with JNI using 'javah'**

```
         ***I am using Window 10 and Android Studio 2.1.2.***
```

> ## Suppose  APP (**JNIP my app Name**) location is
>
> ```
>       E:\test\JNIP and you wrote native methods in JniExample.java file
> ```

**JDK Location is**

```
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin>
```

**JNI Folder Location is**

```
    E:\test\JNIP\app\src\main\JNI (where, you want to create header file)
```

**Class Location is**

```
 E:\test\JNIP\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug\com\example\mpankaj\jnip\JniExample.java
```

**Android.jar location is**

```
C:/Users/mpankaj/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar
```

> First Build your project before running below command

**Write Command on coommand prompt/Terminal for .h file creation**

```
javah -d (JNI Folder Location) -classpath (JAR Locaion);(class Location)
```

**Example Command using above details for Command**

```
   C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_51/bin>javah -d E:/test/JNIP/app/src/main/JNI -classpath C:/Users/mpankaj/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar;E:\test\JNIP\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug com.example.mpankaj.jnip.JniExample
```

> **After this you will get .h file like this** com_example_mpankaj_jnip_JniExample.h

Comment: I meet same problem, help me plz [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261963/error-class-org-opencv-core-mat-could-not-be-found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261963/error-class-org-opencv-core-mat-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score 1):

You can even execute javah from eclipse with much simplicity.
I tried these below steps and they are working I referred the below link for solution http://www.lithiumhead.com/notes/windows_jni

Step by Step Guide

1. Start Eclipse. Preferably create a new workspace called
   WorkSpaceEclipseJNI
2. From the menu select File>New>Java Project
3. Enter Project Name as 01Java_HelloWorld
4. Click Next >
5. Click Finish
6. In the Package Explorer expand 01Java_HelloWorld
7. Right click src folder and select New>Package
8. Enter Name as com.lithiumhead.jni
9. Click Finish
10. In the Package Explorer under 01Java_HelloWorld > src  right click
     com.lithiumhead.jni and select New>Class
11. Enter Name as HelloWorld
12. Click Finish
13. Paste the following code into

HelloWorld.java

```
package com.lithiumhead.jni;

class HelloWorld {
 public native void sayHello();

 static {
  System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  HelloWorld h = new HelloWorld();
  h.sayHello();
}
```

}

1. From the menu select Run>External Tools>External Tools
   Configurations…
2. Highlight Program in the list in the left pane
3. Press the New button
4. Enter Name as javah - C Header and Stub File Generator
5. For the Location browse to locate javah.exe in the JDK installation
   folder (will be something like C:\Program
   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\javah.exe)
6. Enter Working Directory as: ${project_loc}/bin/
7. Enter Arguments as -jni ${java_type_name}
8. Click Apply
9. Switch to the Common tab
10. Select the checkbox next to External Tools under Display in
     favourites menu
11. Click Apply
12. Click Close
13. Deselect Build Automatically from Project Menu
14. In the Package Explorer right click 01Java_HelloWorld and select
     Build Project
15. In the Package Explorer highlight HelloWorld.java
16. From the menu select Run>External Tools>1 javah - C Header and Stub
     File Generator (This will generate the header file for the C code
     com_lithiumhead_jni_HelloWorld.h placed in the bin folder of
     01Java_HelloWorld Java Project.)