# Error: Class org.opencv.core.Mat could not be found

Tags: android, opencv, java-native-interface, javah

When i generating header file with JNI using 'javah' it shows

```
Error: Class org.opencv.core.Mat could not be found.
```

System: Mac OSX

Using: Android Studio and opencv 3.1 for android

Commandline:

```
javah -classpath /Users/lumeng/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar:. com.lumenghz.test.OpencvHelper
```

Who can help me?

**Edit-1**
I also tried

```
javah -d ~/Documents/androidworkspace/RumenTest/test/src/main/jni -classpath /Users/lumeng/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar:. com.lumenghz.test.OpencvHelper
```

But still got the same error:

```
Error: Class org.opencv.core.Mat could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving wrong class path here:

> com.lumenghz.test.OpencvHelper

Give full class path like this:

> ~/Documents/androidworkspace/RumenTest/openCVLibrary310/build/intermediates/classes/debug:. com.lumenghz.test.OpencvHelper

```
  javah -d (JNI Folder Location) -classpath (JAR Locaion);(class Path)
```

example as per your paths-

```
 javah -d ~/Documents/androidworkspace/RumenTest/test/src/main/jni -classpath /Users/lumeng/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar;~/Documents/androidworkspace/RumenTest/openCVLibrary310/build/intermediates/classes/debug: com.lumenghz.test.OpencvHelper
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's working :-)  And the command i posted is also worked.

Comment: I use same command this command :- `javah -classpath D:\Android_sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar;. com.v1.v1golf2.library.CaptureVideo3` 

but getting some error : -Error: `Could not find class file for 'com.v1.v1golf2.library.CaptureVideo3`'.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

I should declare the classpath of opencv-sdk-android which been builded.

So the commandLine should be like this:

```
javah -classpath ~/Documents/androidworkspace/RumenTest/openCVLibrary310/build/intermediates/classes/debug:. com.lumenghz.test.OpencvHelper
```

Comment: I use same command this command :- `javah -classpath D:\Android_sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar;. com.v1.v1golf2.library.CaptureVideo3` 

but getting some error : -Error: `Could not find class file for 'com.v1.v1golf2.library.CaptureVideo3`'.