# how can I get method id for a function returning a generic type in jni?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

```
    jclass queueCls = (jclass)(*env)->FindClass(env, "java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue");
    if(queueCls == NULL) {
        LOGE("can not get class for blocking queue");
                return;
    }
    jmethodID take = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, queueCls, "take",
            "()[B");
    if (take == NULL) {
        LOGE("can not get take method for blocking queue");
        return;
    }
```

and the value of `take` is always NULL. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#take%28%29). I am using `LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]>`.

Appreciate if any example is provided.

Comment: Try `"()Ljava/lang/Object;"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5641641/2760919) answer.

You should consider the `LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]>` object as a simple `LinkedBlockingQueue` on JNI side, because **Java Generics** are resolved at compile time.

I suggest you to use **[javah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17872349/2760919)** to generate the proper native header file with correct JNI signatures starting from the compiled class.

Comment: Yes, I treat the queue as a simple "Object" and cast the return value to jbyteArray at runtime.Thank you for the information